# php code order mysql query table by column name

Tags: php, mysql

I want, using php code, to order a mysql query table by column names (witch are taken "dynamically" - column names are not fixed).
The script only gets the correct column name of each column from the query.

...etc...connect to db..

```
    $query = "SELECT a.name,a.surname,b.email,c.phone 
      FROM users as a 
      inner join users_email as b 
      inner join users_phone as c
      WHERE a.id=b.id AND a.id=c.id ";


if (isset($_GET['orderby'])&&
    (($_GET['orderby']=='name') || ($_GET['orderby']=='surname')||($_GET['orderby']=='email')))
{
    $query .= "ORDER BY" . $_GET['orderby'] . "ASC;";
}

$result = mysql_query($query,$con);

echo "<table><table border=1><tr>";

for($i=0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++){
    $field_info = mysql_fetch_field($result, $i);

    echo '<th><a href="login3.php?orderby='. $field_info -> name .'" >'. $field_info -> name .'</a></th>';
}

while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($row as $_column){
    echo "<td>{$_column}</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: First of all, try using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [Mysqli_*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) inseat of `mysql_*` for your queries, because is deprecated as you can see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-db-query.php) :)

Comment: Please consider using the `mysqli` or `PDO` family of functions instead of the `mysql` family of functions. PHP has advised that all developers stop using the `mysql_` family of functions. http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

Comment: we were thinking the same thing @ErenorPaz!

Comment: He he yes! The more we are, the sooner everyone will forget about that mysql_* :)

Comment: Why can't you use a regular SQL `order by`?

Comment: [$field_info -> name](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-field.php) returns column's name, but you already have it: it's what you are selecting in your query, between `SELECT` and `FROM`. Is the example you provided different from what you really are trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i'm using PDOhere, i'll give you the connection template (insert the variables' names you are using with mysql_conn() and you are done):

```
//try connecting to database
try 
{
  $dbconn_pdo = new PDO(
    'mysql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $db . ';charset=utf8', $user, $password, 
    array(
      PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, 
      PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
    )
  );
}
//catch exception, if connection failed
catch (PDOException $e) 
{
  echo ("Error: cannot connect to database<br/>"); 
  die();
}
```

Given your example, to order the table, you could get column names that needs to be ordered from the link (you will build it later), so the query becomes:

```
$query = "SELECT a.name,a.surname,b.email,c.phone 
      FROM users as a 
      inner join users_email as b 
      inner join users_phone as c
      WHERE a.id=b.id AND a.id=c.id";
```

Here we check ordering:

```
if (isset($_GET['orderby']) && 
(($_GET['orderby'] == 'name') || ($_GET['orderby'] == 'surname') || ($_GET['orderby'] == 'email') || ($_GET['orderby'] == 'phone')))
{
  $query .= " ORDER BY " . $_GET['orderby'] . " ASC; ";
}
```

To get query result, use this:

```
$result = $dbconn_pdo->query($query);
```

Now, column names are already known from the query itself, so no need to call functions to retrieve them (should you really need that feature, take a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php):

```
?>
<table><table border=1>
  <tr>
    <th><a href="so-wwwglro.php?orderby=name">Name</a></th>
    <th><a href="so-wwwglro.php?orderby=surname">Surame</a></th>
    <th><a href="so-wwwglro.php?orderby=email">Email</a></th>
    <th><a href="so-wwwglro.php?orderby=phone">Phone</a></th>
  </tr>
<?php
```

Then, of course, you fetch rows to create the table; the only row that gets changed it's the "while" (we are using PDO, after all):

```
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
```

Then, you only have to create your table, and it's just like your example:

```
{
  echo "<tr>";
  foreach($row as $_column)
  {
    echo "<td>{$_column}</td>";
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

If, instead, you would like to sort columns dynamically, without reloading the page, you should use Javascript, but it's a completely different thing :)

EDIT: Changed from mysql_* to PDO, so that we are not "supporting" deprecated functions.

Comment: ...I tried your code...doesn't get the column name any more. Thank you. In if statement it should be $query .= instead of query .=...

Comment: I tried echo '<th><a href=this_file_name.php?orderby=> ' . $field_info->name . ' </a></th>';....but $_GET is getting nothing...

Comment: I'm setting up a page to test it :)

Comment: http://erenor.net/so-wwwglro.php Here i got something, i'm editing my answer to show you my code

Comment: Thank you very much. My column name are "taken" from the query so I don't have to modify the table column name manually (I modify just the query).

Comment: ...stick to my initial script (steel old mysql)...Finally I displayed link(from column name) correctly with: `echo '<th><a href="login3.php?orderby='. $field_info -> name .'" >'. $field_info -> name .'</a></th>';` Now this stuff doesn't work `if (isset($_GET['orderby'])&&
 (($_GET['orderby']=='nume') || ($_GET['orderby']=='prenume')||($_GET['orderby']=='email')))
{
 $query .= "ORDER BY" . $_GET['orderby'] . "ASC;";
}` The error is `Warning: mysql_num_fields() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp-portable\htdocs\db\login3.php on line 28`

Comment: I don't know if the $_GET function works...(if it gets anything). I will edit my first post with the new script.

Comment: It says that the function `mysql_num_fields($result)` received a boolean. So, `$result` must be a "false" or "true" value. It should be a result set, so maybe the error is in the query. Looking at the query, we can see `"ORDER BY" . $_GET['orderby'] . "ASC;"`. When php puts the `$_GET['orderby']` value, you can see it will become something like `"ORDER BYemailASC;"`, because there are no spaces. Change it to `"ORDER BY " . $_GET['orderby'] . " ASC;"` (as you can see in my example) and let me know :)

Comment: PS: if you use "nume" and "prenume" instead of "name" and "surname", be sure to change the words everywhere they are used, to avoid errors :)

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested it but something like this might work:

```
$sort = 'your_field_to_sort';

while (($row = $result->fetch_assoc())) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

usort($data, function($a, $b) use ($sort) {
    if ($a[$sort] == $b[$sort]) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a[$sort] < $b[$sort]) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

This example assumes you are using mysqli, which you should prefer over the old deprecated mysql functions.

If you still want to stick to the old API then use [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php):

```
[...]

while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

[...]
```

Comment: Sorry. I don't use mysqli yet...I am already new to the "old" sql...Thank you

Comment: You should really consider refactoring (the syntax is nearly the same). I added an example for the old API above. I have not tested it though ;-)

Comment: I do agree with @acme with abandoning old mysql_* :)

Comment: Ok...Thank you for the advice...I will consider it...so if I have to parse a "dynamic" column name (for ordering purpose) from a table...how do I do that ... (without editing manually the table's columns name)?

Comment: Something like `echo ('<th><a href="login3.php?orderby="> '. $field_info -> name .' </a></th>');` $field_info doesn't influence the sorting